# Protector and Charger Circuit for 2P2S 18650 Battery Pack

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, bms

This post is in addition to my previous post of a different design I was exploring.

I am trying to design a custom circuit akin to a BMS that allows for the charging of 2P2S battery pack whilst also providing adequate protection against over/under charging and over/under voltage.

I am using the [BQ77307 IC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq77307.pdf?ts=1704218730457&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fsitesearch%252Fen-us%252Fdocs%252Funiversalsearch.tsp%253FlangPref%253Den-US%2526searchTerm%253DBQ77307RGRR%2526nr%253D2) for protection against these conditions.

When recharging, I will use the [MCP73832 IC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73831-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20001984H.pdf) for each cell (the two cells in parallel).

Could someone check if my design is valid, particularly with the charging aspect of the circuit?
I am not sure from the datasheet if it is acceptable to connect the MCP ICs in series.

[image]

Comment: Lithium is very flammable, just look at a few youtube movies about burning bike or car batteries. I hope you do this kind of experiments in a lab with adequate fire protection, not at home, where your insurance will surely refuse to cover after your house burned down. May I even guess that you are not using new Li-Ion cells, but old ones from a bad ebike battery, which increases the risks even more?